# Unable to create result source showing only users where AD property is not empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, people-search, kql

SharePoint Online here.
I'm trying to create a result source that only contains external users. In local AD we distinguish external users from internal ones with the LDAP property '**company**'. This property contains the external companie's name and is blank to indicate an internal user. 
Since this is not synched to the user profile service we used a script to create a custom user profile property with the same name of '**company**'. 
As a result, this property is available as the crawled property '**People:SPS-Company**'.
 Next, I mapped this crawled property to '**RefinableString135**'.
 So when I launch the query builder for the new result source I cannot seem to find a query that only shows users where '**RefinableString135**' is populated. It always shows all users. 
 I tried `RefinableString135:{searchTerms}` and `{searchTerms} RefinableString135:*`. I read that with KQL one cannot query for 'not null' but the goal I'm trying to achieve doesn't sound too complicated. I guess there is some other kind of logic and I've approached this all wrong. Would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to give those previously empty AD values values in order to make it work. Now I can query for all values not the one I want to be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
RefinableString135<>””
```

[Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work, unfortunately. It shows all results so the query is equal to `RefinableString135:*`. As far as I know empty property values are not indexed in SharePoint.